# returning text in xml using ajax with a function

Tags: jquery

trying to get the getFromWho function to return the recipient text from xml file, I can get it to log the text, but for some reason I cannot get it to return in the function.

```
function preSubmit(){
    var optionTexts = [];
    $("section").each(function(){
        var h2 = $(this).find("h2").text();
        optionTexts.push(h2);
        optionTexts.push("\n");
        $("ol li", this).each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) })
    });
    var splitText = optionTexts.join("\n");
    console.log(splitText)
    splitText += getFromWho();
    return splitText;
}

function getFromWho() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "forWho.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            console.log($(xml).find('recipient').text())
            return $(xml).find('recipient').text();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are using ajax the execution will be asynchronous, means you can't return any value from the ajax callback.

The correct way to solve this is to use a callback method or use the ajax promise.

Ex

```
function preSubmit(callback){
    var optionTexts = [];
    $("section").each(function(){
        var h2 = $(this).find("h2").text();
        //optionTexts.push("<b>");
        optionTexts.push(h2);
        optionTexts.push("\n");
        $("ol li", this).each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) })
    });
    var splitText = optionTexts.join("\n");

    getFromWho().done(function(xml){
        splitText += $(xml).find('recipient').text();
        callback(splitText)
    });

}

function getFromWho() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "forWho.xml",
        dataType: "xml"
    });
}
```

Then

```
preSubmit(function(splitText){
    //Do actions which depends on splitText
});
//You cannot do anything which depends on splitText here as preSubmit is asynchronous
```